# I'd like to make it more simple

Tags: java

I have here my java code that the objective is that the output should look like this: 
problem   NEL01L01A021   問題   NEL01L01A021   英語   11-22-2016   NEL01L01A021/NEL01L01A021-problem.txt

I've done it already but I'd like to make it much more simple. Can you please help me?
        import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class TestTabSeparator {

String str;
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

TestTabSeparator(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    this.strings = strings;
}

void showArrayList() {

    for (int index = 0; index < this.strings.size(); index++) {
        System.out.print(this.strings.get(index) + "   ");
    }
}
}
```

The other class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TabSeparator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList();

    String topicName = "problem";
    String title = "NEL01L01A021";
    String idTitle = "問題";
    String questionNo = "NEL01L01A021";
    String keyword = "英語";
    String comment = "11-22-2016";
    String bodyKey = "NEL01L01A021/NEL01L01A021-problem.txt";

    String[] str2 = new String[7];
    str2[0] = topicName;
    str2[1] = title;
    str2[2] = idTitle;
    str2[3] = questionNo;
    str2[4] = keyword;
    str2[5] = comment;
    str2[6] = bodyKey;

    stringList.addAll(Arrays.asList(str2));
    TestTabSeparator strList = new TestTabSeparator(stringList);
    strList.showArrayList();
}
}
```

Comment: Try [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: why not pack it all in 1 String?

Comment: You may skip some String declarations by assigning your array directly : `String[] str2 = {"problem", "NEL01L01A021", etc...};`

Comment: for `for (int index = 0; index < this.strings.size(); index++) {
        System.out.print(this.strings.get(index) + "   ");
    }` use `for(String s : strings) { System.out.print(s + "   "); }`

Comment: Can't you simply `join` them together?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll give a try. I'm just a newbie in Java programming and you suggestion really makes me happy! Thanks!

Comment: @Berger Sorry man the instruction I have is to assign every string in a variable.

Comment: @Mast I can join them together man but I dont like doing that way because too much code in 1 window.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions. First you can do Arrays.asList directly on your variables instead of first creating array.

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(topicName, title, idTitle, questionNo, keyword, comment, bodyKey)
```

Second showArrayList method can be simplified using String.join.

```
void showArrayList() {
    System.out.print(String.join(" ", strings));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
public class TestTabSeparator {

    private ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

    private TestTabSeparator(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }
    private void showArrayList() {
        strings.stream().forEach(s -> System.out.print(s+"  "));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String topicName = "problem";
        String title = "NEL01L01A021";
        String idTitle = "問題";
        String questionNo = "NEL01L01A021";
        String keyword = "英語";
        String comment = "11-22-2016";
        String bodyKey = "NEL01L01A021/NEL01L01A021-problem.txt";

        ArrayList stringList = new ArrayList(){{
            add(topicName);
            add(title);
            add(idTitle);
            add(questionNo);
            add(keyword);
            add(comment);
            add(bodyKey);
        }};
        TestTabSeparator strList = new TestTabSeparator(stringList);
        strList.showArrayList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was able to discover new in java, the string join. I think it defeated the ArrayList in terms of collecting data as far as String is concern.